# Reducing TimePicker padding

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I am using a TimePicker, which I have scaled down.
But there is a border of spacing around it.

Can someone tell me how to reduce the spacing.
I am trying to use -ve numbers in margin, but i am sure there is a better way of doing it.

```
    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.6"
        android:scaleY="0.6"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24sp"
        android:padding="0dp"
         />
```

Comment: Could you try adding the tag `android:background="#FFFF0000"` and posting a screenshot? I'm wondering if it's the natural size of the background that's causing the extra spacing.

Comment: did you know sp is preferable for the adjusting the textsize you want to use the dp in your marginleft and in margin top

Comment: dp results in errors, eclipse suggests to use sp...

Comment: You are right Brian, the space around it is not because of the timepicket. but still there is a lot of space, which i am not able to get rid off.

i'm not able to post the attachment because i dont have 10 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

You are right Brian, the space around it is not because of the timepicket. but still there is a lot of space, which i am not able to get rid off.

i'm not able to post the attachment because i dont have 10 reputations.